# ¿Cómo seleccionar un subconjunto de mi fichero de datos excel en R con la orden subset?

Tags: r

Tengo un fichero de datos de excel ya leído en R, con las variables Entrega, Nº Transporte, Fecha, Volumen..
Estoy intentando seleccionar los datos de cada día para compararlos día a día. Implemento la orden subset para tomar los datos del día 3 de agosto, el cual aparece en la columna Fecha como : "2020-08-03"

```
Lunes1=subset(datos,Fecha=="2020-08-03")
```

Pero al hacerlo, obtengo una tabla vacía , y no encuentro explicación.
Por asegurarme de que no hay otro nombre oculto al visible, hago un summary para fecha y obtengo:

```
 Min.   :2020-08-03 00:00:00   
 1st Qu.:2020-08-07 00:00:00     
 Median :2020-08-14 00:00:00    
 Mean   :2020-08-15 07:40:33    
 3rd Qu.:2020-08-24 00:00:00    
 Max.   :2020-08-31 00:00:00
```

Por lo que hago :

```
Lunes1=subset(datos,Fecha=="2020-08-03 00:00:00")
```

Pero vuelvo a obtener una tabla vacía.

Answer (score 2):

Lo único que se me ocurre que puede estar pasando, es que tus fechas vengan con milisegundos, y pasa algo así:

```
datos <- data.frame(Fecha = as.POSIXct("2020-08-03 00:00:00.656", 
                                       format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))

subset(datos,Fecha=="2020-08-03 00:00:00")

[1] Fecha
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Si es así, deberías decidir, si los millisegundos es una información útil o no, si no lo es podrías directamente truncar o redondear esta información directamente en la variable, pero si es útil deberías ajustar la consulta por algo así:

```
subset(datos,trunc(Fecha, units="secs") == "2020-08-03")
```

o bien

```
subset(datos,round(Fecha, units="secs") == "2020-08-03")
```

Las dos puedesn arrojar resultados muy distintos, el `trunc()` remueve los milisegundos, en el ejemplo la fecha `2020-08-03 00:00:00.656` será transformada en `2020-08-03 00:00:00`, en el caso de `round()`, obviamente, se redondea, y el valor final sería `2020-08-03 00:00:01`.